# C++ Compiler optimization issue for custom loop iterator

Tags: c++, optimization, clang

I am working on a private project, they have their own contains and templates, there is loop iterator they used for 'for' loop only looks like below:

```
template<class T> class FakeLoopIter
{
public:
    inline FakeLoopIter(const array<T>& from)
        : m_Curr(((array<T>&)from).begin()), 
        m_End(from.end())
    {
    }

    inline FakeLoopIter(const const_array<T>& from)
        : m_Curr(((const_array<T>&)from).begin()),
        m_End(from.end())
    {
    }

    inline void operator++()
    {
        ++m_Curr; 
    }

    inline void operator++(int)
    {
        ++m_Curr; 
    }

    inline T* current()
    {
        return m_Curr;
    }

    inline const T* end()
    {
        return m_End;
    }   

    inline operator T* ()
    {
        return m_Curr;
    }

    inline ubiBool finished() const
    {
        return m_Curr == m_End;
    }

private:
    T* m_Curr;
    const T* m_End;
};
```

There is function using this loop iterator like below:

```
void SampleClass::foo()   
{
    int lastLength = 0;
    for(FakeLoopIter<MyCustomClass *> it(m_array); !it.finished(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)->doSomething(this);
        if( (it+1) != it.end()) //optimized out 
        {
            OwnerType src = (*it)->getOwnerInstance();
            OwnerType dst = (*(it+1))->getOwnerInstance();
            lastLength = (src-dst).getLength();
        }
        else
        {
            lastLength = getLastLengthSafely();
        }
        (*it)->setLength( lastLength );
    }

}
```

After turn on optimization /O2, the logic 'it+1 != it.end()' is been optimized out (compiler think it is always true), which leads crash.

If i change the code like below, it works fine:

```
void SampleClass::foo()   
{
    int lastLength = 0;
    for(FakeLoopIter<MyCustomClass *> it(m_array); !it.finished(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)->doSomething(this);
        MyCustomClass* dest = *(it + 1);
        if(dest != *(it.end()))
        {
            OwnerType posSource = (*it)->getOwnerInstance();
            OwnerType posDest = dest->getOwnerInstance();
            lastLength = (posSource-posDest).getLength();
        }
        else
        {
            lastLength = getLastLengthSafely();
        }
        (*it)->setLength( lastLength );
    }

}
```

It will be greatly thankful if anyone can tell me the optimization rule behind this.

If there is anything unclear about this questions, please let me know, so I can improve it.

PS: I am talking about the clang compiler by the way.

Comment: `((array<T>&)from).begin()` causes undefined behaviour. Don't do that

Comment: If you are still having trouble, plase post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in which the crash occurs

Comment: in the "changed code" you add an extra dereference operation, perhaps that is what you should have been doing in the original code.  It's somewhat confusing trying to read this where `T *` is the template argument given to parameter `T`

Comment: Thank you, @M.M, i have changed the T* in the sample function to avoid confusion with template argument since the function is not belong to a template class.

Comment: Regarding to the crash, it is gone after I changed the code in the way I posted, but I don't understand why the compiler consider (it+1) != it.end() is always true and optimizes it out. and I would like to know the optimization rule behind this.

Comment: What is `(it+1)`?  I don't see any `operator+()` definition in the class. Is there some magic that changes `it+1` to `it++`?

Comment: Indeed, there is no operator+ defined in its original code, but it works like operator+(int n).